# EF Core API HttpGet parameter null

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing an EF Core Web API. When I query with FirstName, the variable gets null. Where am I doing wrong?

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<User> Get()
{
    var urunler = from Users in myDbContext.Users select Users;
    return urunler.ToList();
}

[HttpGet("FirstName")]
public IList<User> Get(string name)
{
    var urunler = from Users in myDbContext.Users where Users.FirstName == name select Users;
    var result = urunler.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `name` parameter is null is because the framework does not know where to populate the name parameter from.

if you change your code to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<User> Get()
{
    var urunler = from Users in myDbContext.Users select Users;
    return urunler.ToList();
}


[HttpGet("{name}")]
public IList<User> Get(string name)
{
    var urunler = from Users in myDbContext.Users where Users.FirstName == name select Users;
    var result = urunler.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

it should work

this will allow you to use the route

```
/firstName
```

the query will then return all people who have the `Users.FirstName = "firstName"`

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use string functions like Contains(),ToLower().I think its case sensitive issue because == operator check exactly same value on both side.
if i misunderstood your issue so explain your issue more.

Comment: I tried all versions. The query is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If your name variable is not empty and if you have same data in your database, you should look a different steps. This code is should work I can't see any problem.

You can open profiler and check your SQL query for find the problem and
You should check your entites end mappings. Problem is should be there.

Comment: When I make a WHERE query, it comes up empty. Can you write an example link about the parameter?

Comment: can you make debug and check name paramether in your action is not empty first.
public IList<User> Get(string name (this))

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameter on route.

```
  [HttpGet("FirstName/{name}")]
    public IList<User> Get(string name)
    {
        var urunler = from Users in myDbContext.Users where Users.FirstName == name select Users;
        var result = urunler.ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

P.s why you don't use async / await?